# When did Kamen Rider Double meet Kamen Rider Decade?

Tags: kamen-rider

In the Kamen Rider crossover film [*Kamen Rider × Kamen Rider Double & Decade: MOVIE War 2010*](https://kamenrider.fandom.com/wiki/Kamen_Rider_%C3%97_Kamen_Rider_W_%26_Decade:_Movie_War_2010), when Kamen Rider Decade and Double meet they recognize each other. Double then agrees to help Decade defeat an enemy from his world.

How did Kamen Rider Double recognize Kamen Rider Decade? When did they meet?

[image: Kamen Rider Double recognizing Decade]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of All Riders Vs Dai-shocker, Double rides in to help Decade and AR Kuuga fight Shadowmoon. Though Double only introduces themselves and never actually talk to Decade.